# Binary Search on a std::string array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, templates, c++11

Below is the code and

```
std::string str[5] = {"Tejas","Mejas","Rajas","Pojas","Ljas"};
std::sort(str,str+5);
size_t test =  bin_search("Ljas",str,5);
```

Here is the generic function  for binary search

```
 template<class T>
    size_t bin_search(T x,  T* array, int  n)
     {
     size_t begin = 0, end = n;
            // Invariant: This function will eventually return a value in      the range [begin, end]
             while (begin != end) {
                       size_t mid = (begin + end) / 2;
                       if (array[mid] < x) {
                              begin = mid + 1;
                       } else {
                                 end = mid;
                       }
      }
     return begin;   // Or return end, because begin == end
}
```

And the Error is

```
 main.cpp|12|error: no matching function for call to 'bin_search(const char [5], std::string [5], int)'|
```

There is a problem with only the `std::string` array, but the `int` array works really fine.
Does it work with string arrays or is there anything missing in the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class T>
size_t bin_search(T x,  T* array, int  n)
```

Expects that you recieve a T and a pointer to T.  When the compiler deducts the types in

```
size_t test =  bin_search("Ljas",str,5);
```

`x` is deduced as a `const char[5]` as all string literals have the type `const char[N]`.  `array` is deduced `std::strign[5]`.  Since a `cont char[]` and a `std::string[]` are not the same type the no function will be generated.  You need to make `"Ljas"` a string like

```
size_t test =  bin_search(std::string("Ljas"),str,5);
```

---

Also note that the collection passed to a binary search needs to be sorted.  If the data is not sorted then you cannot reason what half the element should be in.

Answer (score 6):

As the error message tried to tell you, `"Ljas"` is not `std::string`, it's `const char[5]`. Then the [template argument deduction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) failed since the type `T` could not be deduced (as `const char*` or `std::string`).

You could explicitly cast it to `std::string` to make template argument deduction work well:

```
size_t test =  bin_search(std::string("Ljas"),str,5);
```

or explicitly specify the template argument to avoid template argument deduction:

```
size_t test =  bin_search<std::string>("Ljas",str,5);
```

Answer (score 2):

`size_t test =  bin_search(std::string("Ljas"), str, 5);` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

- You algorithm won't work even if you fix your compile error because a binary search requires a sorted array.
- It isn't necessary to write your own binary search algorithm, the STL already has one: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search
- Your first argument should be a std::string, not a string literal: `bin_search(std::string("Ljas"),str,5);`